# Android Jellybean not booting

Tags: 4.2-jelly-bean, boot-loop

My phone suddenly stopped booting. When I press power button to turn on my phone, I see manufacturer animation in a loop and phone doesn't start.

I didn't do any thing like flashing custom ROM. I don't know what happened to my phone. What should I do now? Is there any hope to fix this?

Phone model : HUAWEI ASCEND G610 U20

Android :     Version 4.2

Internal Memory: 4GB (1.5 GB Usable)

RAM: 1 GB

Comment: Have you tried a factory reset from recovery?

Comment: You are most likely going to have to flash your stock firmware. Let me do a little digging and I'll post some links. Hopefully I can have it to you by the end of the day

Comment: @acejavelin : Yes, I tried doing a factory reset (Power Button + Volume Up thing). But that didn't help. And I lost all data in my internal memory too.

Comment: @asloss : I have only 4GB internal memory available and 1GB Ram. I am not even sure that any new custom rom would even fit into it!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Download [the stock firmware](http://consumer.huawei.com/pk/mobile-phones/support/downloads/detail/ascend-g610-pk.htm?id=27463). The website seems pretty slow and the download is 1.41 GB so this might take some time, but it is the official website. It also includes the official flashing tool, so you may not need to download below mentioned flashing tool.
2. Download [this flashing tool](https://androidmtk.com/smart-phone-flash-tool).
3. Extract the flashing tool to your desktop or wherever you want it. You can use the SD card if you like. In that case, all you need is to put the UPDATE.APP file in dload folder in sdcard, insert sd card to phone, Press Volume Up + Volume Down + Power Button. When Phone vibrates, release power button only, and when upgrade starts release volume keys too. Wait for some time.
4. Follow Steps 6-12 on this website and you should be good to go:
   It has pictures :)

[here](https://androidmtk.com/flash-stock-rom-using-smart-phone-flash-tool)

Be patient this process might take a little while. the first boot will also take some time so don't turn off your phone or disconnect it from the computer before it is done.

If you have any questions feel free to comment and I'll try to help as much as possible as I don't have this phone.

Comment: Thanks Asloss, I downloaded same file but not from huawei site, but from google drive, some user might have put there so I got good download speed. And There was no need to download the flashing tool you mentioned, that 1.4 GB download already includes that.

Comment: Glad I could help! Even if it was only a little haha!

Comment: That download has files for SD card Upgrade or Upgrade using PC, and An instruction manual (official, by Huawei guys) about how to upgrade and precautions. I chose SD Card upgrade, everything gone well and now I am able to use my phone again.